# Where can I store a user accessible Google Slides template?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-slides-api

I'm currently working on a website which allows reports to be generated and saved as a Google Slide via the Google Slides API. The reports are generated using a template slide which [contains placeholder shapes](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/add-shape) which are then populated with graphs and text.

My problem is that the template Google Slides file needs to be accessible to any user who decides to generate a report. But...

- Google Drive can only be authorized via oAuth. Users coming to the site will not be able to authenticate any drive which does not belong to them
- The template cannot be stored in the codebase as the slides API is only able to interact with files stored in the cloud AND it is not possible to download a file in 'Google Slides format'
- It could be possible to store the template on Google Cloud Storage, but it is not possible to import a Slides file without converting it to another format. Attempting to convert the file once it has been uploaded does not produce a new slides file within the cloud storage

Is there anywhere I could store my Google Slides template and have it accessible to my application at all times so that it may generate reports based on that template?

Comment: Maybe you need to share your template to "anyone on the internet" ?

Comment: @Kos other than the security implications, the drive API still needs to be authenticated using oAuth to connect to a drive. Even if the template is shared to "anyone on the internet", they would still need to know to include it within their drive somehow without being invited

Comment: you can try create Apps Script's web app, that will run "as you" (once you deploy it and grant access) and users can access it from web without authorizing, documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: @JackalopeZero have you been able to resolve the problem? If yes, would you mind to type up a short comment/answer?

Comment: The only answer I managed to get from the Google team was to create a globally accessible template, so anyone signing in to download a report would already have access to the template.